# Round or half-round files sold by radius?

Tags: tools, metal, hand-tools

I'm trying to find a half or full-round file of a particular diameter, but it seems to be rarely mentioned (and when it has been, they've been much smaller than I'm looking for).

Are they just not made/advertised/sold this way because they're not expected to be used for such precision - or is there a different term for similar large instruments that might be available in a range of diameters?

Comment: It's a typically a metalworking term, but what you might try to search for is a "broach": http://www.ohiobroach.com/production-broaching.html

Comment: There is also a type of machinists tool called a reamer. These are available to a standard range of sizes and are designed to trim out a predrilled hole to a precision diameter.

Comment: 1/2",1/4",3/16",7/32" ... all on [the first page of Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Hand-Files-Round-Abrasive-Finishing-Products/s?rh=n%3A256181011%2Cp_n_feature_four_browse-bin%3A4637160011) having searched for *round files*. What size do you need?

Comment: Here's everything you'd ever want to know about files : [kmstools.com](https://www.kmstools.com/blog/hand-file-identification/), and an infograph at the bottom that you can DL to identify files.

Comment: @ Michael Karas , a ream will create a perfect hole the size of the team a tapered team is just that it might be the right size on 1 side but way small on the other.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: @FreeMan To be honest I can't remember why I wanted it, but I haven't bought any chainsaw sharpening files or drill bits since I asked, so I'll leave both unaccepted. I should have said why I wanted one and a drill bit was no good... perhaps I already had a rough hole and needed to size it? I have been trying to find a router bit for an exact profile that such a thing could help with, if only it were way longer than I've ever seen any file, so it probably wasn't that either. No idea!

Answer (score 1):

Files are not a precision tool, so they come in a big variation of sizes. If you want a specific size, there are numbered drill bits , letter drill bits and fractional drill bits. Each drill bit above has a ream to make it exact size.

Answer (score 0):

The very asking of this question begs another couple of questions; namely your use and whether this is the best way to resolve this use.

### Chainsaw sharpening files

Come in a variety of diameters in the rough neighborhood of 1/8".

Comment: Come on these are tiny for someone asking about files. If a specific size was given I missed it and may be wrong. Machine files come in many sizes and styles @mazura has the best comment at this point but I do have “bastard” round files some as tiny as 1/16 and my largest as a 1-1/2”.-